# Instalación y configuración WSL ¿Alguien sabe de alguna guía o documentación?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wsl, zsh

Estoy intentando instalar el subsistema de Ubuntu en mi Windows y además quiero meterle el ohmyzsh para que se vea bien. He estado buscando guías y documentación pero algunas o no están muy detalladas o están obsoletas y quería saber si alguien sabe o conoce como configurar eso por que me dan fallos y no consigo que conecten bien.

Aparte también quiero poder meterle el ssh de github para cuando haga las subidas o bajadas no tener que estar metiendo la clave cada 2x3. Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siendo un ordenador Windows, si tienes asociada una cuenta de correo puedes abrir la Microsoft Store y ahí puedes buscar "Ubuntu" o "WSL" y aparecerán diferentes versiones.

Sobre github, puedes configurar con

```
github --global user.name y github --global email
```

esos datos, la contraseña debe ser un comando muy parecido.

Suerte

Comment: gracias por lo del GitHub haber si con eso ya no me pide que se la introduzca cada vez que haga un push